# Will the execute-order-validate architecture produce a lot of invalidated transactions if peers will call the same function?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would like to understand the advantage of the **execute-order-validate** architecture of Hyperledger Fabric compared to the **order-execute** architecture in terms of efficiency.

The **execute-order-validate** approach allows peers to execute the transactions without considering their order.  This allows the peers to run the transactions in parallel during the **execute** phase.

However, based on my understanding, in the **validate** phase, all transactions (except the first one) that will update the same set of keys in the world state will be invalidated to avoid double-spending.

Given this, will the **execute-order-validate** architecture will potentially produce a lot of invalidated transactions?

Below is a sample smart contract that will illustrate my concern:

```
reserveTicket(eventId, ticketingAgencyId, ticketCount){

  //check if there is not enough tickets left
  if (worldState[eventId] < ticketCount) 
    throw "there is not enough tickets"

  worldState[eventId] -= ticketCount;

  if (worldState[eventId + ":" + ticketingAgencyId] == null)
    worldState[eventId + ":" + ticketingAgencyId] = 0;

  worldState[eventId + ":" + ticketingAgencyId] += ticketCount

}
```

In this smart contract, a ticket reservation system is implemented.  For a particular event, there can be many ticketing agencies that can reserve tickets by calling the `reserveTicket` function.

If there are 10 ticketing agencies (e.g., `agency1` to `agency10`) that will make a reservation on the same event (e.g., `event9999`) at the same time (i.e., the orderer will make the 10 transactions part of the same block), does this mean that 9 of the transactions will be invalidated in the `validate` phase since all of them will update the same key in the world state:

```
worldState["event9999"] -= ticketCount;
```

Will this make the `execute-order-validate` less efficient since 9 of the 10 transactions need to be retried?

In an `order-execute` approach, the 10 transactions will not be executed in parallel, however, as long as there are enough tickets left, all the transactions will be successful.

Is my understanding if `execute-order-validate` correct?  If yes, is there a way to avoid invalidating 9 of the 10 transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Here the link to a chaincode example ( from the [official samples repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) ) that may help you to achieve your goal.

[HL Fabric Samples - High Throughput](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/high-throughput)